# rendered 3D Scene to point cloud

Tags: opengl, rendering, point-clouds

Is there a way to extract a point cloud from a rendered 3D Scene (using OPENGL)?

in Detail:

The input should be a rendered 3D Scene.

The output should be e.g a three dimensional array with vertices(x,y,z).

Mission possible or impossible?

Comment: What is a "rendered 3D Scene"? OpenGL only knows how to render, not how to read renders.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Do you yourself render this 3D scene? If so, how? If not, are you attempting to extract the 3D data from another renderer?

Comment: I`m searching for a way, to convert the 3d polygon data(which opengl generates?) to a point cloud.

Comment: @user1048719 OpenGL doesn't generate 3d polygon data. You generate it and feed it to OpenGL, which in turn generates a 2d image from it. Said that it seems your problem is completely unrelated to OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

- Render your scene using an orthographic view so that all of it fits on screen at once.
- Use a g-buffer (search for this term or "fat pixel" or "deferred rendering") to capture
  (X,Y,Z, R, G, B, A) at each sample point in the framebuffer.
- Read back your framebuffer and put the (X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A) tuple at each sample point in a
  linear array.

You now have a point cloud sampled from your conventional geometry using OpenGL. Apart from the readback from the GPU to the host, this will be very fast.

Going further with this:

- Use depth peeling (search for this term) to generate samples on surfaces that are not
  nearest to the camera.
- Repeat the rendering from several viewpoints (or equivalently for several rotations
  of the scene) to be sure of capturing fragments from a the nooks and crannies of the
  scene and append the points generated from each pass into one big linear array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to deconstruct a final rendering (2D) of a 3D scene. In general, there is no capability built-in to OpenGL that does this.

There are however many papers describing approaches to analyzing a 2D image to generate a 3D representation. This is for example what the Microsoft Kinect does to some extent. Look at the papers presented at previous editions of SIGGRAPH for a starting point. Many implementations probably make use of the GPU (OpenGL, DirectX, CUDA, etc.) to do their magic, but that's about it. For example, edge-detection filters to identify the visible edges of objects and histogram functions can run on the GPU.

Depending on your application domain, you might be in for something near impossible or there might be a shortcut you can use to identify shapes and vertices.

#### edit

I think you might have a misunderstanding of how OpenGL rendering works. The **application** produces and sends to OpenGL the vertices of triangles forming polygons and 3d objects. OpenGL then rasterizes (i.e. converts to pixels) these objects to form a 2d rendering of the 3d scene from a particular point of view with a particular field of view. When you say you want to retrieve a "point cloud" of the vertices, it's hard to understand what you want since you are responsible for producing these vertices in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I`m not interested in the final rendering. If a define e.g a polygon, at some point OpenGL has to know each and every point`s coordinates of the polygon in 3D Space. Now I need to get OpenGL to tell me these coordinates.

Comment: In that case, the answer depends on how you provide the vertices to OpenGL. If you use VBOs, there are OpenGL calls that allow you to retrieve their contents. Look in the OpenGL documentation under [glBufferData](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) in the *Associated Gets* section for more info.

Comment: I`m searching for a way, to convert the 3d polygon data(which opengl generates?) to a point cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take your input data and manually multiply it by your transformation and modelview matrices. No need to use OpenGL for that, just some vector/matrices math.